# componentDidMount not called, its not working at all it seems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-dom

I tried many things. Same code is working in my other project but not in the current one

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import getProductCategories from '../../redux/actions/productCategoryAction'
import "./ProductCategory.css"
export class ProductCategory extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        productCategories: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Mounted!');
        this.props.getProductCategories();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-card-body">
                <div className="main-card-container">
                    {this.props.productCategories.map((pc, i) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={i} className="main-card-card" >
                                <div className="main-card-face main-card-face1">
                                    <div className="main-card-content">
                                        <img src={pc.image} alt={pc.alt} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="main-card-face main-card-face2">
                                    <div className="main-card-content">
                                        <h3> {pc.title}</h3>
                                        <p>{pc.description}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    productCategories: state.productCategory.productCategories
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getProductCategories: () => {
            dispatch(getProductCategories())
        }
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductCategory)
```

tried without mapDispatchToProps as:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getProductCategories})(ProductCategory)
```

componentDidMount failing without any error, not showing console.log string as well.

Although i crosschecked with each and every means i do have still can't resolve.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLn14.png)

Found answer all thanks to  Michalis Garganourakis and cubrr
In App.js i was importing this class based component "ProductCategory" with curly braces. importing it without curly braces did the job as i am exporting it as "export default"

Again thanks  Michalis Garganourakis and cubrr

Cubrr answered this on the very first go. it took me lot of time to understand this silly thing :D :D

Comment: When you import this component, do you use `import { ProductCategory } from ...` or `import ProductCategory from ...`?

Comment: Paste your import statements as well

Comment: ProductCategory in mapStateToProps is reducer which is called in the process. I've checked the same via console.log

Comment: Update the post, you have to make it useful for others who'll come here in the future.

Comment: Also, if this code works in another project, then obviously what's different has to do with the surrounding setup, not the code here per se...  Post more about what's different between your two project.  Does one project do SSR?

Comment: I tried to make a dummy project with this specific code to work and it did.

Comment: I think the problem is with the below statement 
static propTypes = {
        productCategories: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}; The statement is fine. Along with this, you need to add defaultProps statement

Comment: no this isn't working either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the image you added, the error seems to occur on `render` function, so the `componentDidMount` never gets triggered for this exact reason.

Try checking if `this.props.productCategories` exists before trying to use `.map()` on it. This should allow `render` function to run succesfully, and this will then trigger the `componentDidMount` as per react's [lifecycle method order](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting)

```js
this.props.productCategories && this.props.productCategories.map((pc, i) ...
```

Also, try removing the `export` on your first row, keeping just the `export default` of your last row where you also make use of `connect` HOC, like:

```
class ProductCategory extends Component { 

// ...

}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductCategory)
```

Comment: componentDidMount is not calling actions and without action state won't be updated "productCategories" is still blank array. that is why it is showing error

Comment: Exactly. while `componentDidMount` comes after render on lifecycle, if render function fails, there will be no `componentDidMount`

Comment: after implementing this it says. getProductCategories is not a function :/

Comment: I've update my answer. This should be caused due to the multiple exports.

Comment: If that solved your issue and did trigger your `componentDidMount`, consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. In that way, you help others with similar issues to find their way :)

Comment: Thanks. You were right the error was due to multiple exports

Comment: I'm happy I could help!

Comment: This is my first experience with stackoverflow. Thanks for making it awesome @ Michalis Garganourakis